'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage' to int or VS
I'm trying to create 2 functions one will get the amount of Excel sheets i have in a single file and the second one based on the amount will filter through them and will bring back only one that is desired based on certain criteria
public ExcelWorksheet GetCorrectSheet(ExcelPackage pck)
    {
        var sheetNumber = GetSheetCount(pck);

        if (sheetNumber > 1)
        {
            foreach (var sheet in pck.Workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                if (sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString() == "Name" &&
                    sheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString() == "Age" &&
                    sheet.Cells[1, 3].Value.ToString() == "PhoneNumber" &&
                    sheet.Cells[1, 4].Value.ToString() == "Occupation" &&
                    sheet.Cells[1, 5].Value.ToString() == "Id" &&
                    sheet.Cells[1, 6].Value.ToString() == "Email"
                    )
                {
                    sheetNumber = sheet.Index;
                    Console.WriteLine("Sheet found" + sheetNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return pck.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetNumber];
        }
        else
        {
            return pck.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        }
    }

    // this function will determine how many sheets are in the excel file
    public int GetSheetCount(ExcelPackage pck)
    {
        return pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Count;
    }

I tried changing to XElement and to parse it to an integer but without success

You need a break; after Console.WriteLine("Sheet found" + sheetNumber); ?
